# Can't seem to find the data from a Supabase bucket request

Tags: reactjs, supabase

const [media, setMedia] = useState([]);

```
  async function getData() {
    const { data, error } = await supabase.storage.getBucket(
      "galerie_dimf2023"
    );

    if (data) setMedia(data);

    if (error) console.log(error);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  console.log(media);
```

This is my code,and it dosen't return an empty array as it would if I would've had row level security activated.But it returns a weird object that has no data:

```
{id: 'galerie_dimf2023', name: 'galerie_dimf2023', owner: '', public: true, file_size_limit: null, …}
allowed_mime_types
: 
null
created_at
: 
"2023-09-14T14:12:47.3253+00:00"
file_size_limit
: 
null
id
: 
"galerie_dimf2023"
name
: 
"galerie_dimf2023"
owner
: 
""
public
: 
true
updated_at
: 
"2023-09-14T14:12:47.3253+00:00"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

cjwqn coiqbnf vqwn fqj wfdkqwfnqwkdmfqlwfklqwmdqjwlcnqkwmq w qnf qwknd ;qwl kfnqwfqwlbfljkqwnf qwj fdqw bfqjwf bqwlk nfqw;kfqnwkfbnqwgfnqwegnbqwekgfnqwfkdqwnf lqwn lkqewf kqwbgqkwnfgkqngqkegfvnewgfvwljngkq nklwqn fk;lqwn gfkqngkqwndqwklfgqew

Comment: What are you trying to get? It seems that your code should be to get files out of a bucket instead fo the bucket details e.g
`const { data, error } = await supabase.storage.from('galerie_dimf2023').list()
`

Comment: You are right,I was getting the details of a bucket instead of the files inside the bucket.The right code was                                                                           async function getData() {
    const { data, error } = await supabase.storage
      .from("software-images")
      .list(null, {
        limit: 100,
        offset: 0,
        sortBy: { column: "name", order: "asc" },
      });          Damn,Supabase is a bit confusing.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then, to help others find this. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code indicates that you are looking for media files as it is implied by `setMedia(data);`.

However, [getBucket()](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/storage-getbucket) will give you the bucket details, so you should be doing this:

```
   const { data, error } = await supabase
   .storage
   .from('galerie_dimf2023')
   .list()
```

Here's the full function as you report in the comment:

```
async function getData() { 
    const { data, error } = await supabase.storage 
       .from("software-images") 
       .list(null, 
         { limit: 100, 
            offset: 0, 
            sortBy: { column: "name", order: "asc" } 
         });
```

It is a good idea to double-check the [storage API](https://supabase.github.io/storage-api/) for extra context.